# How is it possible that multicolumn cells aren't spanning even the width of one of the columns?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I've created a table where multicolumn cells appear to not even be spanning the width of one of the two columns it was told to, and the adjacent multicolumn cell is spanning more than the two columns it was told to.

I find this to be entirely unexpected.

Here's an **example**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Libertinus Serif}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|r|p{2em}|p{1em}|p{1em}|p{2em}|}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{1:}
        & A & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{B-C} & D \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}*{2-4} 
     & 2: &
        a & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{b-c} & d \\
     & 3: &
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{a-b} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{c-d} \\
     & 4: &
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{a-d} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{5:} &
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{a-b} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{c-d} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(Note that I don't usually use vertical dividers, but did in this example to keep track of the edges.)

**Output** of the above example:

[image: Output of code above, with a-b in row 3 less than the width of column A, and c-d in row 3 spanning more than the width of columns B-C and D]

In the output of the example, cell "a-b" in row 3 is told to span 2 columns, but it takes up less space than the single column it's in.  Conversely, cell "c-d" is told to span two columns, but it spans more than three!

What I **would expect** is something more like the following, with changes in red showing what I would expect to be more like two-column-width spacing.

[image: same image as above, but with cells in rows 3 and 5 repositioned so that two-column cells are centered and take up two columns]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Taken together, your `\multicolumn` statements obliterate all usable information about the supposed fixed widths of the underlying columns for use in rows 3 and 5.

Comment: Consider adding a blank first row, which should set the lengths for all fixed-width columns, then killing it, like this: `\begin{tabular}{...} & & & & & & & \\[-\normalbaselineskip] <rest of tabular> \end{tabular}`

Comment: @Mico, interesting.  Why does that data get obliterated?  It seems like the interface provided by `\multicolumn` is a bit at odds with the mechanism of its operation.  I feel that my misunderstanding of how `\multicolumn` works is because the interface is misleading.  Does the first argument not mean "take up _n_ columns", and the columns' positions and widths are already defined the the `p{}`s?

Comment: Your intuition sounds reasonable, but it's not correct. Take the following, deliberately contrived, example: `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \begin{tabular}{p{4in}} \multicolumn{1}{c}{u} \end{tabular} \end{document}`. The `tabular` should be about 4" wide, right? Wrong! It's only as wide as the lowercase letter `u` (plus some whitespace padding, in the amount of `\tabcolsep`, on either side of `u`). That's why I wrote that `\multicolumn` can obliterate the underlying information. Do please study the examples contained in the link to the earlier question to (re)develop your intuition.